# What I'm doing wrong in this find number of unique paths algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

Problem statement: https://pastebin.com/LzvZecyQ

I have 2 input file to test this algorithm.

First:
https://pastebin.com/BtsiZqqn

And I got this output:

> Case #1: 5

(This one is good)

Second:
https://pastebin.com/fTbdbpnW

And I got this output:

> Case #1: 1
>
> Case #2: 1
>
> Case #3: 9
>
> Case #4: 4
>
> Case #5: 101
>
> Case #6: 3.125

**Problem:** All case is ok but the 6th is wrong.

I'm using this code:

```
public class DemoApplication {

    private static final  Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("com.example.demo.DemoApplication");
    private static final String TEMPLATE = "Case #{0}: {1}\r\n";
    private static final String PLANET_START = "Galactica";
    private static final String PLANET_END = "New Earth";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String inputFilePath = "testInput.txt";
        String outputFilePath = "output.txt";

        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(inputFilePath))) { //Create the reader with the file path of testInput.txt
            try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputFilePath))) { //Create the writer with the file path we want the output
                String line = reader.readLine();//skip first row
                int i = 0;//Counter of lines
                Map<String, String[]> planets = null;

                int caseNumber = 0;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {//Get the value of the current line
                    if (!isNumeric(line)) {
                        String[] split = line.split(":");//Split planet name and the paths
                        String planetName = split[0];
                        String[] connections = split[1].split(",");//Split different planets
                        planets.put(planetName, connections);
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        if (i > 0) {
                            writeFile(writer, planets, ++caseNumber);
                        }
                        planets = new HashMap<>();//reset
                        i = 0;//reset
                    }
                }
                writeFile(writer, planets, ++caseNumber);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, MessageFormat.format("IOException: {0}", e));
        }
    }

    private static boolean isNumeric(String input) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.?\\d*");
        return p.matcher(input).matches();
    }

    private static int differentPaths(Map<String, String[]> planets, String planetName) {
        if (planetName.equals(PLANET_END)) {//Last planed to arrive
            return 1;
        } else {
            int accumulator = 0;
            String[] paths = planets.get(planetName);

            for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
                accumulator += differentPaths(planets, paths[i]);
            }
            return accumulator;
        }
    }

    private static void writeFile(BufferedWriter writer, Map<String, String[]> planets, int caseNumber) throws IOException {
        int result = differentPaths(planets, PLANET_START);//First planet from we start
        writer.write(MessageFormat.format(TEMPLATE, caseNumber, result));//Write in file
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? I prefer, if it is possible, an explanation of why is this not working for case 6 instead of giving me the solution. This is because I'm trying to learn the algorithm.

This problem is the 2nd of the tuenti challenge(https://contest.tuenti.net/Contest) if someone is interested I think you can still participate.

Thanks in advance.

**Solution**:

Change the method to write the output casting result to String, doing this, MessageFormat.format doesn't add dot as decimal separator

```
private static void writeFile(BufferedWriter writer, Map<String, String[]> planets, int caseNumber) throws IOException {
        int result = differentPaths(planets, PLANET_START);//First planet from we start
        writer.write(MessageFormat.format(TEMPLATE, caseNumber, Integer.toString(result)));//Write in file
    }
```

Comment: Please post the exact problem statement. Your explanation of the problem is insufficient and hard to understand.

Comment: I'm having issues editing the post and can't add the problem statement on it, I added a link to the problem statement instead. Sorry for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm seems to be working well, perhaps the problem is in the MessageFormat.format method, 3.125 might be 3125, and the dot is just the thousands separator.

Comment: So much thnx it was the problem